# Wifi AP connected without internet for specific ISP on Debian

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, dns, wifi-configuration

I need help getting my home wifi to give me access to the internet on Debian. I am really puzzled because I can connect to ANY other network and I do have internet access, except the one at home and any other from the same ISP. I can always connect to the AP with no problem, and I can ping any site, but I cannot traceroute (running `traceroute <anydomain.tld>` always returns three columns of asterisks); every connection times out. When I connect to my home AP, I have internet for about 20 seconds: I can traceroute, load sites, etc... after this brief window of time, the problems described above start happening. Even more puzzling, my Megasync client seems to be completely unbothered by the lack of internet access (that is, it keeps working uploading and downloading files), as well as `apt` and `apt-get` (I can update and upgrade with no problem), except for two repos: the one for MS Edge, and the one for MySQL Community; neither command can find the addresses for these.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude E5450 running Debian Testing; the wireless adapter is `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)` and it uses the `iwlwifi` driver, which is up to date.

I can connect using USB and Bluetooth tethering with no problem using my Android phone *connected to this very same AP*. Sometimes, after connecting for around an hour to either USB or BT, I can disconnect from it, connect to my wifi AP and then I have internet for some time, sometimes hours. After rebooting, the internet is gone.

I'm guessing it's a DNS problem, because the same AP works well on another distro (Puppy Linux Fossa), and on my phone, and on Windows, and on another Debian laptop. The wifi device is an Intel 7265. The driver (`iwlwifi`) is up to date.

I have the output of several commands, one on a cafe with a different ISP (henceforth, "the other AP"), and one at home; here's `netstat -tun` at the other AP:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:53366     198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:32892     151.101.65.69:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:48134     44.240.37.33:443        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:42396     89.44.168.214:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:58930     66.203.125.13:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:58552     104.16.249.249:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.131:42190     37.220.36.240:443       ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 192.168.1.131:68        192.168.1.1:67          ESTABLISHED
```

This is the output of the same command on my home AP:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:41310   51.158.99.6:20443       FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:50264   91.250.81.52:9001       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:57062   54.36.172.32:9001       FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:55206   31.131.2.17:443         FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:44140   109.228.53.235:443      FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:35930   148.251.22.104:443      FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:33856   82.165.185.89:4492      FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:37456   31.184.218.180:9001     FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:55208   31.131.2.17:443         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    536 192.168.100.117:54158   95.214.54.80:443        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:51776   157.90.179.103:8001     FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      1 192.168.100.117:43938   138.201.227.205:443     SYN_SENT   
tcp        0    537 192.168.100.117:46842   188.114.140.233:9091    FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.117:54296   85.204.121.219:9001     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2806:2f0:5021:fcd:41154 2a0b:e46:1:100::14:443  ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2806:2f0:5021:fcd:41148 2a0b:e46:1:100::14:443  ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2806:2f0:5021:fcd:57424 2001:678:25c:2216:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 192.168.100.117:68      192.168.100.1:67        ESTABLISHED
```

Since I ran a lot of commands, I just leave a link to the relevant Pastebins:

1. `dhcpcd -T wlp2s0`: [other](https://pastebin.com/ZWhJSm38), [home](https://pastebin.com/eeWtYifn) (I only installed `dhcpd5` to run this, then purged it).
2. `nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e wlp2s0 google.com`: [other](https://pastebin.com/n28Z3AsF), [home](https://pastebin.com/F5hnZQEK).
3. `nmap -sn --system-dns 192.168.100.1`: [other](https://pastebin.com/PuYEiD9r) [home](https://pastebin.com/k4BS7Mi5) (I pasted the last command, but I entered the IP for the gateway as the last argument).
4. `nmcli device show wlp2s0`: [other](https://pastebin.com/Hy0suWd9), [home](https://pastebin.com/ztjQ4YZQ).
5. I ran `wireshark` for a few minutes on both APs: [other](https://pastebin.com/KNFUjQkx), [home](https://pastebin.com/DzxyDzsK).

I'm still reading docs to understand what all of the above means, but any guidance or hints would be *very* appreciated!

The following two are specific to this laptop, so there's no need to compare: this is [`iptables -L -vn`](https://pastebin.com/6i5CJhnF), and this is [`nft list ruleset`](https://pastebin.com/nYbSD2CE). The only thing I can gather from these two is that the rules are only defined for `LIBVIRT_*` devices (interfaces?), so as far as I can see there is nothing preventing my wifi device (`wlp2s0`) from accessing the DNS server.

These are the steps I already tried:

- setting the DNS server to `8.8.8.8` and/or `8.8.4.4`;
- deleting all connections from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`;
- installing `resolveconf`; activating and deactivating `systemd-resolved`;
- restarting the AP device;
- switching off IPv6 from the NetworkManager window.

I can't recall if I tried anything else. Please help!

Comment: You have many connections from many corners of the world. You also have many in FIN_WAIT_2 state, which occurs when a server wants to shut down the TCP connection with the client. Are you running torrent software or some other server software?

Comment: Hi, harrymc. No, this laptop is just for mail, sometimes work, social mediab strictly small stuff. I have no servers running here. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't really understand it myself. The biggest difference that I noticed in the Wireshark dump is that your home trace is speckled with calls using `ism:` that look like `ism://192.168.100.37:9431/?nameGateway=3C:17:10:BB:68:33&sslMthd=none#Ver=2.1.`. The only ISM that I managed to find is the "Ivanti Service Manager", but it might be unrelated. Does this ring some bell with you?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that `ism` "protocol"; Google doesn't return anything at all when I search such an address. This is even more baffling than before.

Comment: @harrymc I found [this](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/19956/odd-udp-output-from-router-to-1921681255-any-ideas/) on the Wireshark forums. The main hypothesis is that it corresponds to some sort of VoIP, which is indeed a service my ISP provides. I can't disable it because it's my landlord's phone line.

Comment: (1) I think something is wrong to do with the ISP or the parameters of their modem - you should get in touch with their Support. (2) Please add to your post information about your computer: model, OS, network adapter. (3) Do I understand correctly that if you connect to this AP not via the computer's network adapter, there is no problem?

Comment: As for (3): yes, I can connect to this AP using my phone and tether to my computer via USB or Bluetooth, and I have internet access that way; it's only when using the wireless adapter of this machine that I don't have internet, but I can connect to the AP. I edited the post to contain the specs of this machine.

Comment: @mathbekunkus I can help but notice that your home wifi is using the same IP subnet that libvirt uses...(namely `192.168.100.0/24`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your nft ruleset dump, it seems that `virbr0` on your system has the IP `192.168.100.1/24` configured, which means the prefix route (`192.168.100.0/24`) of it and `wlp2s0` will conflict with each other (and obviously, your laptop probably has the same IP, although not configured on `wlp2s0`, as the router at your home).

Changing the IP subnet/range to use for libvirt in [`virt-manager`](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#The_Virtual_Machine_Manager_.28virt-manager.29) will likely solve the problem. A subnet from [the Class A or Class B private blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) is probably less likely to cause problem as consumer-grade routers tend to use one from the class C private block by default.

Comment: You, good sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! I hadn't noticed that; I was more focused on possible misconfiguration on `wlp2s0`; thank you kindly!!